# how can exclude id with having multiple value?

Tags: mysql

i have 3 store_id (0,1,6) . i only want to get id have storeid <> 0 , but 24340 also have storeid =0 , i also want remove it too

Original:

```
valueid   store_id
24346     6
24345     6
24345     1
24344     0
24340     6
24340     1
24340     0
```

Expected:

```
valueid   store_id
24346     6
24345     6
24345     1
```

tried using store_id NOT IN (0,1,6) or store_id<>0 And store_id<>1 AND store_id<>6 but seeem not working

Comment: So your select statement should be like that : select valueid, store_id from thetable where store_id<>0 group by valueid,store_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
select * 
from my_tbl 
where valueid not in (select valueid 
                     from  my_tbl 
                     where store_id=0);
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4raGrSSZtagsBMDereNzTa/0

> Result:
>
> ```
> valueid   store_id
> 24346      6
> 24345      6
> 24345      1
> ```

Comment: thanks you very must . it worked like a charm

Answer (score 1):

Using aggregation:

```sql
SELECT valueid, store_id
FROM yourTable
WHERE valueid IN (SELECT valueid FROM yourTable
                  GROUP BY valueid HAVING SUM(store_id = 0) = 0);
```

Comment: another worked answer . Thanks you